# Finding labeled dataset for intrusion detection

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification

I want to start ML project about whether Host-Based or Network-based Intrusion Detection. I've been searching about a recent **labeled** dataset but I couldn't find one, maybe because I am new in this field since this will be my first project.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looking for data sets and libraries is Off Topic here.

Comment: I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[KDD cup 1999](http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html) has the dataset that you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry to get to you again. I think the one `kddcup.data_10_percent.gz` is corrupted!! I cannot open it or even convert it in my MAC OS X or even Ubuntu. Is there another link to get the clean one?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your own dataset? I think most people would agree when I say " Each network is different, and the type of attacks and attack durations will also be different depending on the services you have. So a dataset that is good for one scenario is not going to good for another and so are the attributes. Which is why we created this tool which allows you to make your own intrusion dataset and you get to choose your attributes!

Paper:Conference Paper INSecS-DCS: A Highly Customizable Network Intrusion Dataset Creation FrameworkSoftware : https://github.com/nrajasin/Network-intrusion-dataset-creator